# Determine the kernel of a linear map $f:U \to V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $U=<\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}>$ and $V= <\begin{pmatrix}2& 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$>.

Let $f:U \to V$ such that

$$f \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$f \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 6 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

$$f \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 3/2 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}.$$

I have to determine $ker(f)$ and $Im(f)$. Normally, if we work with $R^n$ and the standard basis, I've no problems, but this setting with matrices and non-common vector spaces confuses me: please, could you show me how to work out this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I suppose you mean $f$ goes from $U$ to $V$.

Comment: @Bernard Yes I do. Please, could you help me solve this step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the generators of $U$: $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ (in your very order) and those of $V$: $v_1$ and $v_2$. Note $f(u_1)=v_1+v_2$ and  $f(u_2)$ and $f(u_3)$ are colinear with $f(u_1)$. With this information you can deduce $\operatorname{im} f$ and you can write the matrix of $f$ relative to the bases $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $(v_1,v_2)$.

Indeed \begin{align*}f(\lambda_1u_1+\lambda_2u_2+\lambda_3u_3)&=\lambda_1f(u_1)+\lambda_2f(u_2)+\lambda_3f(u_3)\\
&=\lambda_1(v_1+v_2)+2\lambda_2(v_1+v_2)+\frac12\lambda_3(v_1+v_2)\\
&=\Bigl(\lambda_1+2\lambda_2+\frac12\lambda_3\Bigr)(v_1+v_2),\end{align*}
which shows  the image is contained in the subspace generated by $v_1+v_2$. Conversely, $v_1+v_2$ is attained by $u_1$. So $\operatorname{im} f =\langle v_1+v_2\rangle$.

The above equation shows $\lambda_1u_1+\lambda_2u_2+\lambda_3u_3 \in \ker f$ iff $\,\lambda_1+2\lambda_2+\frac12\lambda_3=0$. It will be a subspace of dimension $2$. You may choose e.g. $-u_1+2u_3$ and $2u_1-u_2$ which are clearly independent, so that
$$\ker f =\bigg\langle\begin{pmatrix}3&0&1\\ 0&2&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2&0&3\\ 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\bigg\rangle. $$

Comment: This is just where I'm confused. Could you show me how to do this?

Comment: @Bernard if $f$ maps the generators of $U$ to scalar multiples of $v_1+v_2$ then it follows that $v_1+v_2$ alone generates $\operatorname{Im}(f)$

Comment: @oldrinb: I know but the O.P. seems to require more details. Perhaps this is a very new subject to him/her.

Comment: oops, I tagged the wrong person -- sorry

Comment: You're welcome… :o)

Answer (score 0):

Since $u_i$ generate $U$ it follows every element of $U$ can be written in the form $\sum c_iu_i$. As Bernard noted, $f$ acts such that $u_1\mapsto v_1+v_2,u_2\mapsto2(v_1+v_2),u_3\mapsto\frac12(v_1+v_2)$. It follows that $\operatorname{im}(f)$ is generated by $v_1+v_2$ alone.

Now, since we know the action of $f$ on these generators of $U$ in terms of the generators $v_i$ of $V$ we can represent $f$ as a matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1/2\\1&2&1/2\end{bmatrix}$$

Just find two independent $(x,y,z)$ such that $x+2y+\frac12z=0$; the easiest trivial examples are $(0,1/2,-2)$ and $(-2,1,0)$, which therefore span $\ker(f)$.